# Which model to use if I need to train sensitive text data and later I want to search back

Tags: openai-api, google-cloud-vertex-ai, huggingface, azure-ai

I am relatively new in AI. I have used a few model in huggingface. But I don’t know how to do for my case.

I need to train the private information in text document so that later, I can ask the model to search from my text document.

For example, my text document would be like this from this link.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/send-api/

> You will need:
>
> 1. A Page access token requested by a person who can perform the MESSAGE
>    task on the Page
> 2. The pages_messaging permission
> 3. The message recipient
>    must have sent your Page a message within the last 24 hours or agreed
>    to receive messages from your Page outside of the standard 24 hour
>    messaging window

I want to ask which permission I need to use Send API.

1. Which model should I use for that (if it is from huggingface)?
2. If there is anything Google or Microsoft offer for that, I would like to know. The only thing is I need to download the model back and later run on my own private server. If possible, training needs to happen on my private server because my text data include sensitive information (like credit card info, etc)